# Java open file window in jframe

Tags: java, swing, browser, jframe, jeditorpane

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8t7tfpuclbm32x9/Screenshot%202015-03-23%2001.00.49.png?dl=0

I am wanting to implement a open file "navigation window" eg: screenshot above, 
Using a Jframe and Jmenu, so when I click open file in the next image, it will open a navigation for compatible file types.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5t4jkxbq6a14rg6/Screenshot%202015-03-23%2001.08.51.png?dl=0

When I open this file I want it to open in the JEditorPane below, this is the relevent chunks of code I believe.

```
webWindow = new JEditorPane();
webWindow.setEditable(false);

JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menu);

JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    menu.add(file);

JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open file...");
    file.add(open);
    open.addActionListener(
    // new detector
    new ActionListener() {
        // when detector is tripped, perform this action
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent enterPress) {
            // gets string from JTextField using the loadWebPage method
            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("c:\\"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

If anything relevent is missing, I can add it

Edit: If I was unclear, what I would like to do is click "open file", browse through my computer's personal files, find the file I want and click on it, opening it in the JEditorFrame.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer that pointed me in the right direction, thanks, I couldnt find a name for what I was looking for so I posted here, assuming it either didnt exist or that I would be pointed in the right direction. I you want to flesh out an answer, I will mark it right so you can get your upvotes for being helpful

Answer (score 1):

> try this code into your **ActionPerformed** method

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
            chooser.setSelectedFile(new File(""));
            chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
            // chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
            if (chooser.showOpenDialog(frame) == JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG) {
            //do when open
            } else {
                // do when cancel
            }
```

Comment: an explanation to go along with your code would make for a better answer